# What's wrong on declaring this .otf font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

This is my declaration code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyOwnFont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../webfonts/MyOwnFont.otf') format("opentype");
}
```

but when I use it:

```
body
{
    font-family:'MyOwnFont';
}
```

I can't see it in the webpage. What's wrong with the declaration?

Comment: Which browser doesn't it work on. It's usually best to run the font through a web-font generator, such as http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator This way, it will generate an `otf`, `ttf` etc version of the font, which will be supported far better, than just a reference to an `otf` font.

Comment: It works! If you put an answer, you will got +1 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually best to run the font through a `web-font` generator, such as http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

This way, it will generate an `otf`, `ttf` etc version of the font, which will be supported far better, than just a reference to an `otf` font.

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'MyWebFont'; 
    src: url('WebFont.eot'); 
    src: url('WebFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('WebFont.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
        url('WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg'); 
}
```